# How to support Chinese characters in .Net Core Avalonia?

Tags: .net, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

The program I compiled cannot display Chinese characters normally on my friend's computer (it can be displayed normally on my Win10 and Deepin Linux), is there any font missing? What fonts need to be installed on the computer?
[image: can not display Chinese characters]

Comment: You don't say whether the target environments are the same or different. Are there any differences between your setup and your friends? OS, OS Version etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Avalonia version 0.9.x you need to explicitly set the font that has the Chinese glyphs, since 0.9.x doesn't support font fallback chains for resolving missing glyphs in the current font. The most stable solution would be to ship such font with the application and use it from resources [like this](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone/blob/d3b47b4ee976eabe6319b6e9ff4d72de57681f4e/ControlCatalog/Pages/TextBoxPage.xaml#L49).

Proper Unicode support is coming to 0.10 which should be available this summer. For now you can try using the [nightly builds](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Using-nightly-build-feed) and see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried to set `fontfamily` according to the method in your link, but I failed, and I described it in detail in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816456). Is there any step I am missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: I try your font file `SourceSansPro-xxx.ttf`, it is work. But my font file is doesn't work...