# How to include external font in Avalonia application without installing it

Tags: .net, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

I try to use a kind of Chinese fonts `HGDH_CNKI.TTF`. I put it into `sbid/Assets/Fonts/` (my project name is sbid).

And then I try it like [this](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone/blob/d3b47b4ee976eabe6319b6e9ff4d72de57681f4e/ControlCatalog/Pages/TextBoxPage.xaml), I use:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddProtocol}" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/HGDH_CNKI.TTF#HGDH_CNKI">新协议</Button>
```

or

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddProtocol}" FontFamily="avares://sbid/Assets/Fonts/HGDH_CNKI.TTF#HGDH_CNKI">新协议</Button>
```

It still doesn't work. Is there any other steps I need to do?

Comment: I doubt that your font is called `HGDH_CNKI` please double-check how the font family is called. Also, make sure to add the font as AvaloniaResource.

Answer (score 1):

I found that **Avalonia do no support Chinese font family**.
I change the font family of the `.ttf` file to English by using FontCreator.
Everything is ok.